# check if the csv file exists and do the condition?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system

Hi I am working on csv file and I have a data I want to append these data to the csv file. But firstly I want to check if the csv file exists if TRUE then just open the csv file and append the data to csv file and save it, if NOT just create a DataFrame and with these data and save it.
Note: I have a csv file in my I want to append the sample of data to my csv file
thanks in advance.

here is my trying.

```
#sample of data
ID = 5
img_Latitude = 38786454
img_Longitude = 1118468

meta_lat = 45778 
meta_long = 886556 

#create a function
def create_csv( ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude,meta_lat, meta_long):
#check if the file is exists, if True
    if os.path.isfile('C:/My/Path/compare_coordinates.csv'): 
#read the csv file  
        df = pd.read_csv('compare_coordinates.csv')
#make pd.series
        data = pd.Series([ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude, meta_lat, meta_long], 
                 index=['ID', 'img_Latitude', 'img_Longitude', 'meta_lat','meta_long'])
#append the data to df
        df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        
    else:
        data = [ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude, meta_lat, meta_long]
        columns = ['ID', 'img_Latitude', 'img_Longitude', 'meta_lat','meta_long']
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns).T
    df.to_csv('C:/My/Path/compare_coordinates.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Check out my updates.. @Mike67

Answer (score 2):

The line `df.append(data, ignore_index = True)` needs to be:

```
df = df.append(data, ignore_index = True)
```

This is because DatFrame.append returns a new DF with the appended lines, it does not append in-place:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the values that needed must be saved in variable so for the line
`df.append(data, ignore_index = True)` to be edited to `df = df.append(data, ignore_index = True)` and for the getting value of file exists or not as following codes:

```
def create_csv( ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude,meta_lat, meta_long):
    Path = os.path.isfile('My/path/compare_coordinates1.csv')
    if Path==True:
        df = pd.read_csv('compare_coordinates1.csv')
        data = pd.Series([ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude, meta_lat, meta_long], 
                         index=['ID', 'img_Latitude', 'img_Longitude', 'meta_lat','meta_long'])
        df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        
    else:
        data = [ID, img_Latitude, img_Longitude, meta_lat, meta_long]
        columns = ['ID', 'img_Latitude', 'img_Longitude', 'meta_lat','meta_long']
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns).T
    df.to_csv('My/path/compare_coordinates1.csv', index=False)
```